# Understanding context in perl

Tags: perl

I am ramping up on Perl programming and understand some basics of Perl. As per my understanding, if an array is assigned to scalar, it will store number of element in scalar. However, I am not clear in terms of hashes. For example, I saw this line:

```
my $variable = {};
```

I am not able to understand, how this `$variable` is still working as hash? What am I missing here?

Comment: `{}` is not a hash, it's a hash reference.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with context.

Comment: my bad. I understand it now. I was coming from Python background and thus confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` creates a **hashref**, which is a scalar.

You need to dereference it to access the items inside it.

```
my $hashref = { foo => 1 };
say $hashref->{foo};

my %hash = ( foo => 1 );
say $hash{foo};
```

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more details.